# tomcat не считывает данные из контекста

Tags: java-ee, tomcat

Настроил проект. Собрал его мавеном. Настроил томкат.
Почему то в файл который он создает себе для дальнейшего считывания

```
"C:\{user}\.IntelliJIdea2018.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_sk"
```

содержит только `<Context path=...>`, а прочие настройки из моего файла конфигурации не скопировались.

Answer (score 1):

ошибка заключалось в том что при поиске контекста томак автоматически проверяет синтаксис файла configUser.xml и если синтаксис содержит ошибки томкат его не видит. но название файла может в памяти сохраниться. и получается словно файл подключен.

решение - открыть файл в ИДЕ и проверить синтаксис. я забыл поставить /.

после этого все отработало.